# How to get a Visual Studio Code project from Power Builder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, powerbuilder

I'm working on a project built with Power Builder 12.7
There is a module to translate the code from Power Builder to .net in C# in Power Builder.
The code produced is available in .net, however, there is no project file (tree) to be loaded in Visual Studio Code. The code is available to be run in Power Builder only.
How to debug it in Visual Studio Code ?

Comment: the module used is PB WPF migration tool with MSBuildVersion="2.0" & ToolsVersion="4.0"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about project. But if you have project in Visual studio, you can debug PowerBuilder Exe through Visual studio. Check native code debug option in debug tab of visual studio project properties and select exe and then debug.